# Skip or exit command if R goes over specified memory limit

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

I would like to run a block of code that skips or exits a command if R goes over a specified memory limit at any time. To illustrate a related example, the following code will skip to the next iteration of the for loop, if the code block takes more than a specified time limit. It will print: '1', 'skip', '2'

```
params = c(1,4,2)
for(i in params) {
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      evalWithTimeout({
        Sys.sleep(i)
        print(i) 
        }, 
        timeout = 3) #go to next iteration if block takes more than 3 seconds
      }, 
      TimeoutException = function(x) cat("skip")
     ) 
   }
```

I would like to do something similar, but skip or exit a command if R goes over a memory limit instead. For example, how can I make the following code print: '1', NOTHING, '2'. Note the second matrix with 1000 rows should be skipped before it is fully built. Also, I will not know the size of the matrix/object that needs to be skipped beforehand, I will only know the memory_limit

```
unknown = matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol = 1000, nrow = 1000) #unknown object
memory_limit = object.size(unknown)-100000 #known memory limit that happens to be just under the object

##Evaluate_in_memory_limit##{ 
  print(nrow(matrix(rnorm(1*1), ncol = 1, nrow = 1)))
  print(nrow(unknown)) #this should be skipped
  print(nrow(matrix(rnorm(2*2), ncol = 2, nrow = 2))),
 limit = memory_limit
}
```

Comment: You don't want to skip if it goes over the memory limit but if it *would* go over the memory limit. That's a completely different and much more difficult question. I'd even say it's not possible.

Comment: I don't mind if R goes over the _specified limit_, since that limit is lower than the _true_ memory limit on the computer/R job. As long as R breaks or skips the command just after that specified limit is hit I am ok, just like the for loop I posted skips to the next iteration just after 3 seconds. I assume that that the for loop doesn't skip at exactly 3 seconds but probably 3+epsilon. Hence It would still be ok if R breaks the command after it reaches memory_limit+epsilon for a reasonably small epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

You could calculate the size of the vector (matrix) beforehand, if you know the length of it in advance.

For

- integers: 40 + 4 * n bytes
- numeric: 40 + 8 * n bytes

should be the formula for vectors. Check with e.g.

```
sapply((1:3)^10, function(n) object.size(numeric(n)))
# or for matrix
sapply((1:3)^10, function(n) object.size(matrix(numeric(n))))
```

Then use `system('free')` on unix, to determine free memory.

Create your elements in a `for` loop and use the check in an `if` condition to `next` the loop, in case used memory will exceed available.

Comment: Let me clarify in the question that I will not know the size of the vectors/matrices beforehand. The actual code is much more complex and involves algorithms with lots of computations.